# ListView is not displaying correctly when I make a CAST

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-arrayadapter, google-cast

I have a module in an app for casting some content to chrome cast. The layout I display on the cast has a dinamic list view where I put some data.

The problem is that the `listView` does not respect the `layout` for its `rows` and is not displayed correctly (the size and spacing between the views in the rows are not correct), but the other elements does.

I have 'normal' `activities` on the phone which also uses `listviews` for displaying EXACTLY the same data and work perfect.

Any idea about why it is not working well?

Here is the code:

Layout for cast:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/blueLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_background"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/infoHeadLayout"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="51dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="64dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:letterSpacing="0.19"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="3sp"
        android:text="@string/b"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="27sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/infoHeadLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="62dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="354dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/blueLayout">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="826dp"

        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:letterSpacing="0.09"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="10sp"
        android:text="@string/name"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rankText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="719dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="75dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:letterSpacing="0.09"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="10sp"
        android:text="@string/rank"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/nameText"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/priceText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="610dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="75dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:letterSpacing="0.09"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="10sp"
        android:text="@string/price"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/rankText"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/changeText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="449dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="75dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:letterSpacing="0.09"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="10sp"
        android:text="@string/change"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/priceText"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="300dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="75dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:letterSpacing="0.09"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="10sp"
        android:text="@string/market_cap"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/changeText"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/supplyText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="181dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="75dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:letterSpacing="0.09"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="10sp"
        android:text="@string/supply"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/mText"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="75dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:letterSpacing="0.09"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="10sp"
        android:text="@string/volume_24_hr"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/supplyText"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/contentRemoteLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/infoHeadLayout">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/dataList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The row for the listView has exactly the same layout than the infoHead constraintLayout

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: @NoumanCh sorry! Here it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you wrote, I guess you have a row layout defined for the adapter and that all the data for each row is inside a ConstraintLayout. I found the solution on changing the constraint layout to relative layout.